# calculate the average of duplicated rows

Tags: r, dplyr, average, region, rscript

I have a dataset like this and i want to calculate the average of values in column covered_percentage. I need to combined the duplicate region into one row, while calculating the mean over the  covered_Percentage column. This the short file but i have a large file with the same dataset. How to do this thing in R into large dataset.

```
region         values   covered_Percentage
ref|OR4F5       583     96.84 
ref|OR4F5       339     100.00 
ens|ENST00000455207 0   0.00 
ref|SAMD11       120    100.00 
ref|SAMD11       198    100.00 
ref|NOC2L        202    100.00 
ref|NOC2L        120    100.00 
ref|ATP7B        120    99.17 
ref|ATP7B        290    99.66 
ref|ATP7B         206   99.52
```

I am expecting the ouput like this:

```
region          average
ref|OR4F5        98.42 
ens|ENST00000455207 0.00 
ref|SAMD11          100.00 
ref|NOC2L         100.00 
ref|ATP7B          99.45
```